# Passing Block to Function

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, block

I have the following function

`- (void)loginWithCompletionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL))completion`

How do I call it? How do I pass a BOOL as a block? I've tried several ways and I don't seem to understand how this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing "a `BOOL` as a block", you're passing a block that will later be passed a `BOOL`.

```
[thingy loginWithCompletionBlock:^(BOOL didSomethingInteresting){
    // Your code here, using didSomethingInteresting, such as:
    if( didSomethingInteresting ){
        // Do something even more interesting
    }
    else {
        // Do something boring
    }
}];
```

`loginWithCompletionBlock:` is presumably going to go off and try to log in to some service. When the attempt has ended, either in success or failure, your block, which is a piece of executable code, will be run, and will be passed a `BOOL` value by `loginWithCompletionBlock:`

Incidentally, the name of the `BOOL` can be whatever you like, although usually the API you're using will give it a name (such as `success`) to indicate its meaning.

Answer (score 1):

It's implemented as:

```
- (void)loginWithCompletionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL))completion
{
    BOOL result = NO;

    // Do the login thing.

    completion(result);
}
```

Calling it would be like so:

```
[object loginWithCompletionBlock:^(BOOL success) {
    if (success) {
        // It worked
    } else {
        // Oh No!!
    }
}];
```

Hope  this helps.